# BroadcastChannel .asFlow() but it is not working Android

Tags: android

Blow error I am getting:

Using 'asFlow(): Flow' is an error. 'BroadcastChannel' is obsolete and all corresponding operators are deprecated in the favour of StateFlow and SharedFlow
What will be the work around of it if not using StateFlow and SharedFlow?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.